# Angularjs - Function not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, function

I am a very beginner at HTML5, CSS and Angular. I tried to write a simple code to program a button that could change the value of a boolean, just to check how the connections are done.
The code is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
</script>

<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<button ng-click="myFunction">Click Me!</button>
<br>
<p>
{{myBool}}
</p>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myBool = "true";
    $scope.myFunction = function() {
      if ($scope.myBool == true) {
        $scope.myBool = false;
      } else {
      $scope.myBool = true;
      }
};
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I press the button, nothing happens. Can someone tell me why?
Any help is welcome because, as you can see, I am quite lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `()` at the end of `myFunction`. It should be:
`<button ng-click="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>`

Also, you have initialised `$scope.myBool` as a String rather than a bool:
`$scope.myBool = "true"` should be `$scope.myBool = true`

Comment: Great, that worked!
And how do I initialize it as a bool, @keithm ?

Comment: @user2211939 - use `$scope.myBool = true;`